# ListView Issue?

Tags: android, listview

I am using List View to request permissions for android.I have created a custom adapter. The problem is, in the list view only the first element of the adapter array is visible(TextView), rest of the items are invisible.

Below is the code reference:

Custom Adapter:

```
private class ListViewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>{
        private int layout;

        private ListViewAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<String> objects){
            super(context,resource,objects);
            layout = resource;
        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
            ViewHolder mainViewHolder = null;
            if(convertView == null){
                LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
                convertView = inflater.inflate(layout,parent,false);
                ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();
                holder.textView = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.permision_list_view_text);
                holder.switchCompat = (SwitchCompat)convertView.findViewById(R.id.permision_list_view_switch);
                convertView.setTag(holder);
            }else{
                mainViewHolder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
                mainViewHolder.textView.setText(getItem(position));
            }
            return convertView;
        }

    }
```

Initializing List View:

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_permission_request_dialog, container, false);
        ListView lv = (ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.permission_request_list_view);
        getPermissionArray();
        Log.d("permissions",permissions.toString());
        lv.setAdapter(new ListViewAdapter(getContext(),R.layout.permission_dialog_listview_row,permissions));
        return  view;
    }
```

Array Adapter :

```
public void getPermissionArray(){
        permissions.add("Request 1");
        permissions.add("Request 2");
        permissions.add("Request 3");
    }
```

List View row item layout :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:paddingHorizontal="20dp"
    android:paddingVertical="10dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/permision_list_view_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
        android:textColor="@color/colorBlack" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat
        android:id="@+id/permision_list_view_switch"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

I am not understanding why the list view in incomplete.

Below is the screen snap of the issue from my mobile device(Motorola G3)
[image]

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: the answer from @Dhaval should work, but really i am surprised to see that the first item is mapped.. you are calling setText only in recycled items, no item to be recycled normally in your case, so its really strange that the first is shown, is your list backed from bottom(stackFromBottom)? ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@NonNull
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
            View rowView = convertView;
            if(rowView == null){
                LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
                rowView = inflater.inflate(layout,parent,false);
                ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();
                holder.textView = (TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.permision_list_view_text);
                holder.switchCompat = (SwitchCompat)rowView.findViewById(R.id.permision_list_view_switch);
                rowView.setTag(holder);
            }

            ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) rowView.getTag();

            // Set your permission data here using holder

            return rowView;
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

You are setting the text of the list items in the wrong position:

```
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder mainViewHolder = null;
        if(convertView == null){
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
            convertView = inflater.inflate(layout,parent,false);
            ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.textView = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.permision_list_view_text);
            holder.switchCompat = (SwitchCompat)convertView.findViewById(R.id.permision_list_view_switch);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }else{
            mainViewHolder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
            //mainViewHolder.textView.setText(getItem(position)); // not here. This else section is reached only when the rows are getting recycled. 
        }
        mainViewHolder.textView.setText(getItem(position)); // here
        return convertView;
    }

}
```